# Apply transition in accordion panel heading

Tags: html, css

I have an accordion in my `html` page,I need to move text within the heading(panel-title) to move a little bit right on hover using css3 transition

What i have tried is given below

HTML

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading headtext">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
      Collapsible Group Item #1
    </a>
  </h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
  <div class="panel-body headtext">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry</div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
      Collapsible Group Item #2
    </a>
  </h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
  <div class="panel-body">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry
</div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

css:

```
.panel-title > a {
color: #43C3E8;
}
.panel-title > a:hover {
color: #F06426;
padding-left:20px;
text-decoration:none;
outline:none;
transition:all 0.2s ease 0s;
}

.panel-heading {
transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}
```

After doing this what i get is on hover transition is applied to the text within anchor tag.But when cursor is removed text moves faster.I want this transition time to be same as that of hover.

Answer (score -1):

Add the transition in the element and not in :hover

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding: 20px;
    background: black;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover {
    background: red;       
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lw8UM/